# Glass GDK - disable head gestures on LiveCard

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I would like to disable head gesture while the user is on my LiveCard.  This app is using head movement to update the display, and if user looks up down quickly the display turns off.  I know it is possible to do this in an [immersion by using getWindow() and setting flags](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/view/WindowUtils), but to my knowledge there is not a way to get an instance of the window of a LiveCard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible within a Live Card by design. If you want to override the built in Glass head gestures, you must use an immersion.

In this case it may be appropriate to use a Live Card to show a preview of what the immersion will contain. Then when the user taps on the live card, they can enter the immersion where they can use head gestures as a control input.